# Find an event in a calendar

Tags: google-calendar-api

I'm writing an app that reads a Google Sheet that I have read access to. This is working just fine. It contains upcoming dates for things. The sheet contains usually no more than 20 - 30 upcoming events. Events that have passed are ignored.

I need to take these upcoming events and add them to a calendar. Adding events is ok. The problem is that if the app runs again say a week later, the events that are already on the sheet are added again, so I need a way of searching for an event in a calendar based on the date of the event. If I find an event at that date and time, then I can ignore it and move to the next one. It seems that searching for an event requires a calendar ID and an event ID. Is there a way to search for an event by giving a date and time, and say a partial summary?

Failing that, any other options? The data in the Google Sheet I have read access to only. My app doesn't store anything locally. The intention is to read the sheet and add events but not add duplicate events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get events you either use [events.get](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/get) where you provide  the `calendarId` and `eventId` to fetch a specific event or [Events.list](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/list) to get all events.

Comment: The trouble with this approach is that I have about 20 - 30 events I'm reading from a Google Sheet, and then I need to either keep re-querying the calendar for each one returning all events, or return all events first and then query the events list in code which isn't a great a approach. I have found a way to do it though using the MaxResults=1. This way when I query an event on a given date and return 1, I know I have a match. The calendar will never have more than one event on a given date.

Comment: I was rather hoping that as Google is a company famous for providing search tools, I would be able to search for an event based on things like the event summary, or date. You can't search for an event if you don't know the event ID up front, which is the problem I have.